# checking database in android

Tags: android

I have to check whether a database exists or not in android?? how can i check? It should return a boolean value after checking?plz provide me with the code.

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
private boolean databaseExists() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
            SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        if(checkDB != null){
            checkDB.close();
            return true;
        } else {
            //database does not exist
            return false;
        }
    } catch (SQLiteException e) {
        //database does not exist
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: And here `DB_PATH` should be like this: `"/data/data/YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME_IN_MANIFEST/databases/"`.

Comment: Yes, and should be constructed from your Context - `context.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/"`

Comment: thank you!! now i am able to check for the database . the code was really very useful for me.